# Python bar graph problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, graph

I'm trying to create a bar graph in python based off number of individuals in certain zip codes.
I have about 120 zip codes, with my highest number of individuals being under 200.
I can't seem to find a code online that is working -- keep getting
"ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape"

I don't know if I'm inserting too much data at once, but I need all 120 data enteries on the X axis on one bar graph. If I try to do it with only 3 enteries, it works.

Help..

tried all the online codes I can find

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have developed already? Its easy to guide you that way

Comment: I've used from this website : https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/  --------the one labelled Default: various text sizes, positions, and angles ; I want the graph to look like that

Comment: this is another i tried ; import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

 

growthData = {"X": ["1", "2", "3", .....],

             "Y":[1,2,3,....]};

dataFrame  = pd.DataFrame(data = growthData);

dataFrame.plot.barh(x='X-axis', y='y-axis', title="X v Y");

plot.show(block=True);